# Bluetooth file transfer hangs when I send large files

Tags: android, bluetooth

I've implemented bluetouth file transfer according to the example: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html

I've faced with an issue: when I do transfer of a large (50-100Mb) file in the most cases the
transfer process is stuck at any point of the transfer process. Log info says that process stops at the point of write(sender) and read(receiver).When stuck - the total bytes number recorded by sender to a stream is always exceeds the amount of bytes have been read by receiver.The subtraction: received - sent data is equal to 4-7 Kb.

It seems that in certain moment the read method can't do actual READ.

Sometimes 100Mb trasfer passes successfully.

Could you please help me with that?
Thanks in advance

**Receiver :**

```
            try {
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(mSocket.getInputStream());
                File file = new File(root, progressData.file.getFileName());
                FileOutputStream fileStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fileStream);
                DialogsCaller dialog = DialogsCaller.getInstance();

                long bytesRead = 0;
                int len = 0;
                long size = progressData.file.getFileSize();
                int bufSize = Constants.BUFFER_SIZE * 8;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[bufSize];
                int timeOut = 0;
                int maxTimeOut = 16;

                while (bytesRead < size) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "BEFORE AVAILABLE " + bytesRead);
                    while (bis.available() == 0 && timeOut < maxTimeOut) {
                        timeOut++;
                        Thread.sleep(250);
                    }

                    long remainingSize = size - bytesRead;
                    int byteCount = (int) Math.min(remainingSize, bufSize);
                    Log.w(TAG, "BEFORE READ " + "currentSize : "
                            + bytesRead + " byteCount " + byteCount);

                    len = bis.read(buffer, 0, byteCount);

                    Log.w(TAG, "AFTER READ " + "Len " + len);
                    if (len > 0) {
                        timeOut = 0;
                        Log.w(TAG, "BEFORE WRITE " + bytesRead);
                        bos.write(buffer, 0, len);
                        bytesRead += len;
                        Log.w(TAG, "AFTER WRITE " + bytesRead);
                        dialog.setProgress(
                                progressData, (int) bytesRead);
                    }
                }
                bos.flush();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Callback.post(e);
                Log.e(TAG, "Receiving problem");
                mHandler.obtainMessage(MessageType.CANNOT_RECEIVE_DATA)
                        .sendToTarget();
                throw e;
            } finally {
                if (bos != null) {
                    try {
                        Log.i(TAG, "FILE CLOSE");
                        bos.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Callback.post(e);
                    }
                }
            }
```

**Sender :**

```
    try {
        File file = new File(progressData.file.getFilePath());
        FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fileStream);
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(
                mCurrentSocket.getOutputStream());

        long sentBytes = 0;
        int len = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[Constants.BUFFER_SIZE];
        DialogsCaller dialog = DialogsCaller.getInstance();

        while ((len = bis.read(buffer)) > -1) {
            if (len > 0) {
                Log.w("F_" + TAG, "BEFORE " + "currentSize : " + sentBytes
                        + "Len " + len);
                bos.write(buffer, 0, len);
                bos.flush();
                sentBytes += len;
                Log.w("F_" + TAG, "AFTER " + "currentSize : " + sentBytes);
                dialog.setProgress(progressData, (int) sentBytes);
                // SystemClock.sleep(120);
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e2) {
        Callback.post(e2);
        Log.e(TAG, "Sending problem");
        mHandler.obtainMessage(MessageType.CANNOT_SEND_DATA).sendToTarget();
        throw e2;
    } finally {
        try {
            if (bis != null) {
                bis.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Callback.post(e);
            Log.e(TAG, "Stream not closed");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can throttle while you are sending data...few milliseconds delay before you send the next chunk of data..Also reduce the buffer size based on the target device..I had faced similar issue.After tuning the buffer size based on target device it works..You will have to implement some logic to get the target device.

The blutooth communication in android is flaky(because of different radios and implementation) you will have to try different things before it starts working properly on all the devices.